# SQL that should never return anything, but does

Tags: sql

I came across the following SQL statement:

```sql
    SELECT A.NAME
    FROM   THE_TABLE A
    WHERE  A.NAME LIKE '%JOHN%DOE%'
    AND    ((A.NUM_FIELD/1) - (A.NUM_FIELD/2)*2 <> 0)
```

That last condition, `"((A.NUM_FIELD/1) - (A.NUM_FIELD/2)*2 <> 0)"` is what baffles me. Depening on the implementation of order of operations, it should always result to `0` or `A.NUM_FIELD / 2`.

How does SQL still return records from this view? If it always results to half the original value, why have it? (This is a delivered SQL package)

Comment: Order of operations is already determined by the parentheses except for the multiplication, which will occur before the subtraction.

Comment: What is the SQL data type of `A.NUM_FIELD`?

Comment: ANSI SQL does not specify the type when dividing two integers.  SQL Server does integer division, so 1/2 = 0.  Most other databases seem to do floating point, so 1/2 = 0.5.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I didn't see where in the OP's question it stated that the `A.NUM_FIELD` was in integer field.  That's why I was asking.

Comment: @HolgerBrandt NUM_FIELD is of type INTEGER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What SQL implementation is this?

As noted,

```
(x/1) - (x/2)*2
```

is equivalent to

```
X - (2*(x/2))
```

which, if integer division is being performed  yields 0 or 1 depending on whether the value is even or odd:

```
x x/2 2*(x/2) x-(2*(x/2))
- --- ------- -----------
0   0       0           0
1   0       0           1
2   1       2           0
3   1       2           1
4   2       4           0
...
```

if so, it seems like an odd way way of checking for odd/even values, especially since most SQL implementations that I'm aware of support a *modulo* operator or function, either `x % y` or `mod(x,y)`.

The seemingly extraneous division by 1 makes me think the column in question might be floating point. Perhaps the person who coded the query is trying to check for jitter or fuzzyness in the low order bits of the floating point column?

if you modified the query to return all the intermediate values of the computation:

```
SELECT A.NAME                    as Name      ,
       A.NUM_FIELD               as X         ,
       A.NUM_FIELD / 1           as X_over_1  ,
       A.NUM_FIELD / 2           as X_over_2  ,
       ( X.NUM_FIELD / 2 )
       * 2                       as 2x_over_2 ,
         ( A.NUM_FIELD / 1 )
       - ( A.NUM_FIELD / 2 ) * 2 as Delta ,
       case when ( ( A.NUM_FIELD / 1 ) - ( A.NUM_FIELD / 2 ) * 2 ) <> 0
       then 'return'
       else 'discard'
       end as Row_Status
FROM   THE_TABLE A
WHERE  A.NAME LIKE '%JOHN%DOE%'
```

and then executed it, what results do you get?

Comment: Hit the nail on the head -- it must be a odd/even check. Since it's a packaged SQL statement, they probably prefer to do it this way so it won't error if the SQL implementation doesn't support mod statements.

Answer (score 7):

Probably integer division, so an odd `NUM_FIELD` is going to be one less.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx) says:

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is
>   an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

Answer (score 2):

if the NUM_FIELD is an integer, and an odd one- then

```
(A.NUM_FIELD/1) - (A.NUM_FIELD/2)*2
```

is equal to one